# Regular Expression Repeating Group or Explicit Pattern

Tags: .net, regex, performance

I am writing a parser for itemised levels:

```
1.0.0.0.0
  1.1.0.0.0
  1.2.0.0.0
2.0.0.0.0
```

I wrote the regex to match this pattern to use a non-repeating group:

```
\d{1,4}(?:\.\d{1,4}){4}
```

But in review my co-worker suggested this re-write:

```
\d{1,4}\.\d{1,4}\.\d{1,4}\.\d{1,4}\.\d{1,4}
```

Is this a subjective thing? Or is one better than the other? The latter is easier to read to someone who doesn't know regex syntax well. In this case performance is not an issue, but would one perform better on larger targets?

The regex engine will be .Net.

EDIT: I am reading all the comments and replied. Thanks for the input everyone.

Comment: First one is better no doubt and more readable to my eyes at least.

Comment: second one is best because there is no backtracking occurs in the second one whereas backtracking would occur in the first one..

Comment: In the absence of capturing groups there is no difference. With capturing groups, the second approach has an advantage that each number would be available in a separate capturing group.

Comment: @AvinashRaj backtracking occurs in both cases.In second one in casse of failure there will bebacktracking.

Comment: for this particular input, i didn't find any backtracking in the second case.

Comment: Compare it to larger data, you'll see the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a totally subjective thing, there's no significant difference between them in performance or function.  FWIW, I think the first is much clearer and easier to see your intent, the second requires a careful scan and as I'm scanning I'm thinking that there **must** be some difference in each group otherwise you'd have used the first approach.